Why is Applescript so slow when looking up UI element properties?
I've been playing around with a little script in AppleScript to look up UI elements in a program by their name. This is basically the function:
on getElementByClassAndName(targetName, targetElements)
    repeat with uiElem in targetElements as list
        set elName to (name of uiElem)
        if (elName is targetName) then
            return uiElem
            exit repeat
        end if
    end repeat
    return false
end getElementByClassAndName

And here is an example of its use with TextEdit:
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "TextEdit"
        set win to front window
        set myElement to my getElementByClassAndName("Minimize", entire contents)
        log (myElement)
    end tell
end tell

The logic is simple: go over the UI elements in a window, check if the name is equal to a provided string. The problem is that it can take 10-20 seconds depending on the application. If you add a counter, you can see that even if it is not checking that many elements (say, 100), it is ridiculously slow.
The part that is slow is clearly set elName to (name of uiElem). If you remove this and replace it with, say, set elName to false, the script executes almost instantly (but of course does not find the element).
It is amazing to me that looking up the name property is so slow. By comparison, if you instead just add a log(uiElem) in there (without looking up the specific name property), it executes instantly as well. So log is somehow able to get the name info (and lots of other info) much faster than accessing the actual name property directly. Madness.
Is there a way to possibly speed this up, to more directly reference properties of UI elements? It feels bizarre that I can log(entire contents) and other gigantic lists instantly but cannot iterate over the elements in them without increasing the runtime by a factor of 100 or more.
I have tried more unwieldy ways to reference the name, and they seem to take the same amount of time. Is there a faster way to do it? (Why is it so slow?)

Here is a simpler approach to take. Instead of looping through every possible ui element, you can use the whose filter.
tell application "TextEdit" to activate
tell application "System Events" to tell process "TextEdit"
    
    set fw to front window
    
    -- if you know you're looking for a button
    set mb to "minimize button"
    buttons of fw whose description is mb
    
    -- or… if you aren't sure what the element type is
    UI elements of fw whose description is mb
    
end tell

Some notes and a revision:
First, here are example properties of a minimize button in textedit:
{minimum value:missing value, orientation:missing value, position:{317, 26}, role ¬
description:"minimize button", accessibility description:missing value, focused:false, ¬
title:missing value, size:{14, 16}, value:missing value, help:missing value, ¬
enabled:true, maximum value:missing value, role:"AXButton", entire contents:{}, ¬
subrole:"AXMinimizeButton", selected:missing value, name:missing value, ¬
description:"minimize button"}

Note that name has a missing value. Unfortunately, this is typical. Many applications will have a value for the description though — in this case, it is 'minimize button'.
If you know what you are looking for, then that simplifies things.
Second, if you only have an idea of what to look for, eg 'minimize', then you can use contains. You might get extraneous results but when you see the desired result you can get its properties to find the specific text of the description:
tell application "TextEdit" to activate
tell application "System Events" to tell process "TextEdit"
    set fw to front window
    set ec to UI elements of fw whose description contains "minimize"
    --> {button 3 of window "Untitled" of application process "TextEdit"}
end tell

on Slowness and errors
As to why your script is so slow… I would guess that it's because you are asking it to do too much and it has some errors. Also, a scope issue (see below). It's actually going through every ui element that is present when textedit is the active application, including all of the menus. In this case, you know that you are looking for a window element so restrict the search to the window.
Also, you have some stuff that should generate errors in your script but because it is inside the handler, you aren't seeing the errors.
Most importantly, the handler has a different scope than the main script does. System Events knows all about ui elements but applescript only sort of does, so the tell block must also be inside the handler. In addition to this absence resulting in failure, it is also likely bogging down the script. Given that the handler commands are specific to system events, you have to put most of the handler inside a tell block, eg…
tell application "System Events" to tell process "TextEdit"

The return false command can be outside the end tell line but otherwise, I'd put the rest of the handler inside.
You can't always add coercion to a repeat statement. targetElements is already a list so including as list in pointless and introduces an error.
Also, you may find that errors are generated when trying to get the description. I would put the commands that are inside the repeat loop inside a try block.
So, here is a revised version of your script that should work and take a fraction as long to complete.
tell application "TextEdit" to activate
tell application "System Events" to tell process "TextEdit"
    set myElement to my getElementByClassAndName("minimize button", entire contents)
    -- properties of myElement
end tell

on getElementByClassAndName(targetName, targetElements)
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "TextEdit"
        repeat with uiElem in targetElements
            try
                if ((get description of uiElem) is (targetName)) then
                    return contents of uiElem
                    exit repeat
                end if
            end try
        end repeat
    end tell
    return false
end getElementByClassAndName


FWIW, here are about ten lines of the results from the log. It's just getting into the apple menu. Overall, there are 418 items. Since it never actually finds the desired element, it goes exhaustively through them all. When I restricted the same document to the front window, it returned 10 items:
    {window "Untitled" of application process "TextEdit", scroll area 1 of window "Untitled" ¬
    of application process "TextEdit", text area 1 of scroll area 1 of window "Untitled" ¬
    of application process "TextEdit", scroll bar 1 of scroll area 1 of window "Untitled" ¬
    of application process "TextEdit", scroll bar 2 of scroll area 1 of window "Untitled" ¬
    of application process "TextEdit", button 1 of window "Untitled" of application process ¬
    "TextEdit", button 2 of window "Untitled" of application process "TextEdit", button 3 ¬
    of window "Untitled" of application process "TextEdit", menu button "Edited" of ¬
    window "Untitled" of application process "TextEdit", static text "—" of window "Untitled" ¬
    of application process "TextEdit", static text "Untitled" of window "Untitled" of ¬
     application process "TextEdit", menu bar 1 of application process "TextEdit", menu ¬
     bar item "Apple" of menu bar 1 of application process "TextEdit", menu "Apple" of ¬
    menu bar item "Apple" of menu bar 1 of application process "TextEdit", menu ¬
    item "About This Mac" of menu "Apple" of menu bar item "Apple" of menu bar 1 ¬
    of application process "TextEdit", menu item "System Information…" of menu "Apple" ¬
    of menu bar item "Apple" of menu bar 1 of application process "TextEdit", menu ¬
    item 3 of menu "Apple" of menu bar item "Apple" of menu bar 1 of application process ¬
    "TextEdit", menu item "System Preferences…" of menu "Apple" of menu bar ¬
    item "Apple" of menu bar 1 of application process "TextEdit"}

